# Why doesn't my hash work in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have this phonebook program that looks up all the contacts, deletes a contact, and adds a contact. I created a hash global variable called `contactList`. However, the program fails to recognize this. What did I do wrong?

```
class PhoneBook
  contactList = hash.new
  def Add(newContact = {})
    flag = false
    if newContact.length < 1
      return flag
    else
      flag = true
      newContact.collect do |name, number|
        contactList[name] = number
      end
      return flag
    end
  end

  def delete (targetName)
    if !contactList.has_key?(targetName)
      return false
    else
      contactList.delete(targetName)
      return true
    end

  end
  def displayContact (targetName)
    number = -1
    if contactList.has_key?(targetName)
      number = contactList(targetName)
      puts "Contact name : #{targetName}, Contact Number, #{number}"
    else
      puts "#{targetName} doesn't exist in the phonebook"
    end
  end
  def displayAllContacts
    if !contactList.empty?
      contactList.each {|name, number| puts "Contact name: #{name}, contact number #{number}" }
  else
    puts "You don't have any contact details your phonebook"
  end
  end
  end
```

Comment: Can you please add the error message you are getting? IMHO the problem is that you are using bad syntax for creating new hash. Use `Hash.new` instead of `hash.new`.

Comment: I believe you were right. It was an undefined method, but it appears that contactList was declared as a local variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have defined ***class local variable*** `contactList`, whereas you wanted to have an ***instance variable***.

Remove this line

```
contactList = hash.new
```

and add the following method:

```
def contactList
  @contactList ||= {}
end
```

P.S. there is no such thing as `hash.new`, you most likely meant `Hash.new`.

P.P.S. By Ruby naming conventions your variables/methods names should be snake-cased, not camel cased.
So it should be `contact_list`.